# Hardware RAID in CentOS 6.2

Tags: centos, raid, hardware, raid1

I have a ServeRAID-BR10il SAS/SATA PCIe Controller RAID O and 1 Standard. Do you have any suggestions how to install it in CentOS 6.2? All the tutorials I found are only software RAID.

Hope you guys can help. I would appreciate if you can give me some references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure RAID volume in RAID controller. CentOS will see RAID volume as standard block device.

Comment: Hi Kruno, thanks for answering! Can you give me any hints where to start searching for methods? I'm not really familiar with these stuffs and I don't know where to start. I've been searching for two days now and I feel like a little lost.

Comment: During server boot you will get a option enter RAID controller configuration. There you can create RAID volumes that will be visible to OS. I have not used that controller model, so I can't give you specific instructions.